# WiFi ad-hoc mesh network made of 10 Android smartphones

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, ad-hoc-networks

re.:

WiFi ad-hoc mesh network made of 10 Android smartphones

I have a number of wifi, GPS,  accelerometer enabled smartphones (Android 5.) and would like to build ad-hoc mesh network.

I read:

https://www.bing.com/search?q=wifi+ad-hoc+mesh+network&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=wifi+ad-hoc+mesh+network&sc=0-24&qs=n&sk=&cvid=0E5462D3C6E34B53BCF69993119AC7F7

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network

related question:
Windows adhoc mesh network
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129382/windows-adhoc-mesh-network

I plan to start from static topology, close proximity, supporting every peer can communicate with other peer node, to study redundancy, reliability and to visualize traffic in the form of the graph ( vide traffic in car navigation).

I would like to study how much time and bandwidth is spent on updating routes vs. delivering data.

If successful I plan to study dynamic topology, implementing GPS geolocation and visualization of the wifi nodes in Google Maps, wifi traffic supported and visualized.

Once implemented I plan to add solar charger to every wifi, GPS enabled smartphone, since charging 10 smartphones in outdoor is not easy for a number of different geolocation.

Ok, I am aware, ad-hoc mesh network is not hot today but what is hot, GPS-enabled smartphone can be today purchased at pocket money, making the project feasible.

At the same time I would like to read about wifi ad-hoc mesh metwork projects, made of 10+ ... 100+ smartphones, since large numbers of smartphones are readily available among operators

Ok, I need to test first which wifi adopter modes are supported.

Building such network is my old dream, so I appreciate your suggestions and comments.

My personal budget is limited but I can offer bounty since I can buy more smartphones of the same make and model ( Android 5.) to make software installation, configuration more friendly.

related questions:
[ad hoc network in android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47877/ad-hoc-network-in-android)

[Why can't my device see an ad-hoc WiFi network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/why-cant-my-device-see-an-ad-hoc-wifi-network)

[Connect Android device as wifi adapter to a PC to create an ad-hoc network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/connect-android-device-as-wifi-adapter-to-a-pc-to-create-an-ad-hoc-network)

[Connect android phones through adhoc wifi network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19129/connect-android-phones-through-adhoc-wifi-network)

[Does any version of Android support ad-hoc connections?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/does-any-version-of-android-support-ad-hoc-connections)

Comment: just read
https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ad-hoc-networks/info

as advised

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=ad-hoc+mesh+network&user=&room=

could you explain entries generated by search results for

"wifi ad-hoc mesh network" ?